# navigate between tab bar using swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, swipe

I want to navigate between my tab bar using swipe gestures. What is the easiest way to do that? I tried something like this...

```
import UIKit

class postAdViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)    
    }

    func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (sender.direction == .left) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "favourireviewcontroller") as! UIViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if (sender.direction == .right) {

        }
}
```

If I try to swipe right nothing happens. The app crashes when swiping left the following error message

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f924380a730

Answer (score 4):

Well if you want to navigate through you `tabBar` you should implement a `swipeGestureRecognizer` for `.left` and `.right` and then work with the  `tabBarController?.selectedIndex`, something like this:

```
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped))
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped))
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

func swiped(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.direction == .left {
        if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! < 2 { // set your total tabs here
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex += 1
        }
    } else if gesture.direction == .right {
        if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! > 0 {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Swift4 example of swiping left and right right through a TabBar controller.

Things I don't like about this solution:
- seems like you should be able to register the handler once and distinguish the direction within the handler itself but I wasn't able to easily do that.
- I'm also curious how to do a gesture that includes a drag for visual effect. I'm think I need to include a PanGesture as well in order to pull that off.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

}
```

And then the handler:

```
@objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.direction == .left {
        self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex += 1
    }
    if sender.direction == .right {
        self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex -= 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly modified version of an earlier suggestion that is ready for **Swift 5** and iOS 12.

The real advantages are:

1. it uses `guard` statements so you don't have to mess with unwrapping the `tabBarController` and the `viewControllers` in the handler
2. it doesn't require a hard-coded number of tabs — it just gets it from the `viewControllers` array.

I also cleaned it up a bit to make it a little less verbose. It has been tested with Swift 5 running on iOS 12 (and it should be fine on iOS 11.4, since that was my minimum deployment version that this was tested on).

Add these to `viewDidLoad` (or other appropriate location of your choosing):

```
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipeGesture))
swipeRight.direction = .right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipeGesture))
swipeLeft.direction = .left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

Then add this as your handler for the events:

```
@objc func handleSwipeGesture(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
  guard let tabBarController = tabBarController, let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers else { return }
  let tabs = viewControllers.count        
  if gesture.direction == .left {
      if (tabBarController.selectedIndex) < tabs {
          tabBarController.selectedIndex += 1
      }
  } else if gesture.direction == .right {
      if (tabBarController.selectedIndex) > 0 {
          tabBarController.selectedIndex -= 1
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, the swipe is not animated tough, do you know how to animate it?

Answer (score 1):

try using the Swift 4 selector syntax:

```
//below code write in view did appear()
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(swiped))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
  // below code create swipe gestures function

  // MARK: - swiped
   @objc  func swiped(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.direction == .left {
        if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! < 2
        { // set here  your total tabs
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex += 1
        }
    } else if gesture.direction == .right {
        if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! > 0 {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Swift 3` selector syntax:

```
let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:))
```

like so

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nextButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:))
    //leftSwipe.direction = .right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
}



func handleSwipes(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .left) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "favourireviewcontroller") as! UIViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    if (sender.direction == .right) {

    }
}
```

`Swift 3` introduced this feature to enable the compiler to check whether the `function` you're specifying actually exists. It is therefore much saver than the concepts before.